# Spring JPA uses deprecated TLS version

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new to spring-boot and JPA.
I have successfully connected my spring application to MySQL database using JPA.
However, I see the following warning being printed:

> WARN: This connection is using TLSv1.1 which is now deprecated and will be removed in a future release of Connector/J.

How can I upgrade the TLS connection to use either TLS 1.2 or 1.3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a fix for the problem. I added `enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2` to the connection URL.

For example:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?enabledTLSProtocols=TLSv1.2
```